# sql for loop php only gives me last 3 values in the array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

So I have taken data from a table and i'm trying to pair the 'main folder' with the 'parent_id' but when I display the results the final array only contains the final three results in the database. I am very very confused.

I have already done this with an array of 'main folder' paired with 'id' for parent_id = 0. It works absolutely fine. I am bamboozled.

```
//This for loop works absolutely fine
while($parents[] = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    //Adding values from sql table row by row into parents[]
}

for($i = 0; $i < (count($parents) - 1); $i++) {
    $ParentsArray[$parents[$i]['mainfolder']] = $parents[$i]['id'];
}

//Problem starts with this for loop below

while($children[] = mysqli_fetch_array($subResult)) {
    //Adding values from sql table row by row into children[]
}
var_export($children);

for($b = 0; $b < (count($children) - 1); $b++) {
    echo $b;
    $ChildrenArray[$children[$b]['mainfolder']] = $children[$b]['id'];
}
var_export($ChildrenArray);
```

Comment: What are the possible values of `$children[$b]['mainfolder']`? Of the field mainfolder in the query that is represented by $subResult.

Comment: array ( 0 => array ( 0 => '19', 'id' => '19', 1 => 'Link 1', 'mainfolder' => 'Link 1', 2 => '1', 'parent_id' => '1', ), 1 => array ( 0 => '20', 'id' => '20', 1 => 'Link 2', 'mainfolder' => 'Link 2', 2 => '1', 'parent_id' => '1', ), 2 => array ( 0 => '21', 'id' => '21', 1 => 'Link 3', 'mainfolder' => 'Link 3', 2 => '1', 'parent_id' => '1', ), 3 => array ( 0 => '22', 'id' => '22', 1 => 'Link 1', 'mainfolder' => 'Link 1', 2 => '31', 'parent_id' => '31', ),

Comment: Those are the values all the way up to id = '30'.

Comment: In that sample there are only 3 values of mainfolder - so if that is representative, then you can only expect to have three entries in your `$ChildrenArray` becuase it is keyed on `mainfolder`

Comment: It may be that you want to collect all of the matching records (I think that is it) and your line should then be: `$ChildrenArray[$children[$b]['mainfolder']][] = $children[$b]['id'];` Probably likewise for the `$ParentsArray`

Comment: @RichGoldMD No I just want partner up the 'mainfolder' values with the 'parent_id' values so I can use them to make a subfolder like directory with the parent Array values. So the array would look more like this:

array(0=>array('Link 1' => '1')1=>array('Link 2' => '1')2=>array('Link 3' => '1')4=>array('Link 1' => '2')5=>array('Link 2' => '2')6=>array('Link 1' => '31')

Comment: @RichGoldMD The links will be substitued in the end for individual values. They are just a placeholder at the minute.

Comment: Your array replaces the value of $ChildrenArray['Link 1'] every time it finds another mainfolder = 'Link 1', so only the last such record will persist in the array. From your recent comment I surmise that the lie should probably read: `$ChildrenArray[] = [$children[$b]['mainfolder'] => $children[$b]['id']];`